# Comparing all Contents of a list to all lines within a text File

Tags: python, if-statement, readlines

Below I have a list identifiers where values are appended within for loop logic not shown, this part is fine as it's quite basic.

The next part is where I am quite confused as to what I am doing wrong, so I open a local text file and readLines here, I use a for loop to iterate through those lines. If any of the lines in the textfile match any of the lines in the identifiers list then I do not want to send an email (email function is fine). If the ID isn't in the textFile I want to write this id from identifiers list to the text file, the way it is working at the minute it does not seem to do anything.

```
identifiers = []
....
identifiers.append(rowList[0])
....
fo = open('localDirectory/textFile.txt', 'r+')
content = fo.read().splitlines()
for id in content:
    if any(i in id for i in identifiers):
        print("No email to send")
    else:
        fo.write(identifiers[i]+'\n') **Write new ID to indentifiers text file**
        #Send Email
```

Comment: Opening the file in `'a'` mode means you are not actually reading anything from it. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Yes was a typo, updated correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have multiple lines in identifiers that you might want to add, a straight if/else doesn't work. So you need to add a flag to see if you added lines or not, which you test for later to see if you need to send an email.

```
with open('textfile.txt', "r+") as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()

    id_added = False
    for i in identifiers:
        if i not in content:
            f.write(i + '\n')
            id_added = True

        if id_added:
            # Send email
        else:
            print("no email to send")
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need touse for loop in if comparison, since you have been searching if a string from identifiers contained in line from file. Here is right comparison

```
for id in content:
    if id not in identifiers:
        print("No email to send")
    else:
        fo.write(identifiers[i]+'\n') **Write new ID to indentifiers text file**
        #Send Email
```

Comment: This will print out "No email to send" for each line in the content that does not match an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over your content, as you already do that in the list comprehension. Also, consider using with open(), so you automatically close your file.

```
identifiers = ['patternA']

with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()

if any(i in identifiers for i in content):
    print("Present")
else:
    print("Not Present")
```

Comment: Just realised this doesn't do what you need, as it doesn't give you the line from content in your else section, so you can't add it to the file.